# Model Data Changes But View Still Same Angular2

Tags: angular

im writting simple authentication system on angular2 my problem is MY Main Navbar data changes but doesnt except in a view because my HEADER in a main renderer

Login Logic

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/authentication.service';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

declare var jQuery: any;
declare var popupAc: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'as-giris',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    error = '';
    users: User[] = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private _elRef: ElementRef,
        private userService: UserService) {
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        jQuery('.form-control').keypress(function(){
            jQuery('.log-status').removeClass('wrong-entry');
        });
    }

    login() {
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result === true) {
                    this.userService.getUsers()
                        .subscribe(users => {
                            this.users = users;
                    });
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                } else {
                    jQuery('.log-status').addClass('wrong-entry');
                    jQuery('.alert').fadeIn(500);
                       setTimeout( "$('.alert').fadeOut(1500);",3000 );
                }
            });
    }

}
```

User Service For Data getting

```js
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        // Authorization Tokeni Ayarlanıyor
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': this.authenticationService.token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        // Kullanıcı Headeri Gönderiliyor
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/Hesap/Detay', options)
            .map((response: Response) => 
                response.json().detay
         ); 
    }
```

Navbar Logic

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../_services/authentication.service';
import { User } from '../../_models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../_services/user.service';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'as-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.html',
 styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css'],
 providers: [AuthenticationService, UserService]
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() isLoggedIn: any;
 @Input() users: User[];
 constructor(private router: Router, 
    private userService: UserService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){
 }
 
 ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.users);
 }

 ngDoCheck() {

 }

 logOut(){
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
 }
}
```

can i write console log this users data but i cant refresh navbar view

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="profile-nav">
                    <div class="profile-nav-text">
                        <div class="profile-nav-text-name">
                            Hoşgeldiniz {{users.KullaniciAdi}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-nav-text-job">
                            Krediniz : {{users.Kredi | number:'1.2-2'}} TL
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="profile-nav-pic">
                    <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000245527464-i1i2a3-large.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="openRightSidebar"><p style="color: #fff200;margin: -3px 0 10px;">ONLİNE İŞLEMLER<i class="material-icons">apps</i></p></a>
      <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" style="padding-right: 0px;">
      <ul class="nav-actions" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0;">
          <li>
              <i style="color: #f2cc10;" class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <a class="topup_bill">YENİ ÜYELİK</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <i style="color: #fff;" class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <a routerLink="/giris" class="topup_bill" style="color: #fff;">GİRİŞ</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
```

i create getting data logic in login component in router-outlet maybe problem this ? because my navbar inline main html over router outlet

```
<as-navbar></as-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<as-footer></as-footer>
```

Comment: If users is an array, then it should be `users[0].KullaniciAdi` something like this

Comment: i can write data in navbar problem not this. Problem on if i logged in navbar cant refresh view need reload page